# jQuery. get text() to preserve blanks/spaces

Tags: jquery, whitespace

How do I get jQuery text() to preserve blanks? I want

```
 $("#ele").text("a     a");
```

to actually show up with the spaces in between.

I have created a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/ZX4x9/

`.html()` works, but then I'd have to convert the other entities first (`<`, `>`, `"`, etc.). And, it seems that `text()` should be able to do this.

Comment: If you look at the source, you will see that it actually inserts as many spaces. But the browsers collapses multiple consecutive spaces into one.

Comment: How about `text("a        a".replace(/ /g, '\xA0'))`, is that appropriate in your case?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem is not with `.text()`. If you want consecutive and other stray spaces to show up, you can use `white-space: pre` for your `<li>`s:

```
ul li {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

See **[this](https://jsfiddle.net/ZX4x9/1/)**

Comment: Awesome! I had no idea you could do that.